# Nested iteration inside a 2D list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, grouping

I have a list like this, What I wanna do is I want all the values which are followed by 'A' element.

```
mylist = [['B', '\n\t\t'], ['A', 'val1'], ['B', '1*'], 
['A', 'val2'], ['B', '2'], ['A', 'val3'], 
['B', '1'], ['A', 'val4'], ['B', '2'], 
['A', 'val5'], ['B', '2'], ['A', 'val6'], 
['B', '1'], ['B', '3']]
```

Like if I pass `val1` as the output should be `1*`

**Input**

```
val2
```

**Output**

```
2
```

**Input**

```
val6
```

**Output**

```
13
```

Ignore any other entry

I have tried this but It isn't working

```
tag = "A"
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    #print(mylist[i][0])
    #print(i)
    if mylist[i][1] == tag:
        print(mylist[i][1])
        for j in range(len(mylist)):
            print(i+j+1)
            if mylist[i+j][0] != 'A':
                print(mylist[i+j][1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using index handling

```
tag = "A"
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    #print(mylist[i][0])
    #print(len(mylist))
    if mylist[i][1] == tag:
        print(mylist[i][1])
        for j in range(len(mylist)):
            #print("index",i+j)
            if mylist[i+j][0] != 'A':
                print(mylist[i+j][1])
            if (i+j+1) >= len(mylist) or mylist[i+j+1][0] == 'A':
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group items. Then create a mapping via a dictionary comprehension. Using `itertools.islice` avoids the need to create new lists in the second step.

```
from itertools import groupby, islice
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [list(j) for _, j in groupby(mylist, key=itemgetter(0))]

res = {i[0][1]: ''.join(map(itemgetter(1), j)) for i, j in 
       zip(islice(lst, 1, None, 2), islice(lst, 2, None, 2))}

{'val1': '1*',
 'val2': '2',
 'val3': '1',
 'val4': '2',
 'val5': '2',
 'val6': '13'}
```